# Why fragment is not displaying data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am still getting to grips with Android and I am stuck on this problem.

I would like to pass a fragment ID (eg. int postion from the method Fragment getItem(positon) to the fragment so it's value can determine a specific row in an array
Here is a bit of code :

```
// collecting data to pass to fragment
        SoundArrayParcel arrayToSend = new SoundArrayParcel();
        arrayToSend.setInt(arrayImgSet1);

        bundleFrag.putParcelable("dataResId", arrayToSend);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), bundleFrag);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter); ....
```

....
Here is where I pass the value of fragment Id by using the int position of the getItem() along with getCurrentItem() (to test the results I would achieve using one or the other)

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final Bundle fragmentBundle;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle data) {
        super(fm);

        fragmentBundle = data;

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // Initialising new fragment
        final SoundFragAdapter f = new SoundFragAdapter();
        // bundle array position

        bundleFrag.putInt("fragIntIdP", position);
        bundleFrag.putInt("fragIntIdCI", mPager.getCurrentItem());
        Log.i("SoundActivity", "int position is : " + position);
        Log.i("SoundActivity", "Value currentItem is : "+ mPager.getCurrentItem());

        // passing data to fragment
        f.setArguments(fragmentBundle);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

...(NUM_PAGES = 6)

Here is the SoundfragAdapter code :

```
public class SoundFragAdapter extends Fragment {
private int fragPosition;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // get data from bundle passed by activity
    Bundle argsIn = getArguments();
    SoundArrayParcel arrayToReceive = (SoundArrayParcel) argsIn.getParcelable("dataResId");
    final int[][] arrayResId = arrayToReceive.getInt();
// get int fragment Id to use in array
    fragPosition = argsIn.getInt("fragIntIdP");


    // inflate the fragment
    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sounds_frag, container, false);


    // info array row def : img src; sound src; voice_src; toast_msg_src
    // fragIntIdP int value from bundle equal to frag position
    // fragIntIdCI int value frm bundle equal to currentItem frag positon

    Log.i("Rootview", "fragPosition is : " + fragPosition);

    // Find sound img src
    ImageView imageSound = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_for_sound);
    //set img for corresponding fragment Id
    imageSound.setImageResource(arrayResId[fragPosition][0]);
    // Once the Image is clicked, the sound is played
    imageSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootview) {
            // Start playback.
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), arrayResId[fragPosition][1]);

            mp.start();
            // Once Sound has stopped release MediaPlayer resources
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);


            // Little msg confirming end of sound
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), arrayResId[fragPosition][3], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    // Find voice img
    ImageView imageVoice = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_for_voice);
    imageVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View rootview) {
            // Start playback.
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), arrayResId[fragPosition][2]);

            mp.start();
            // Once Sound has stopped release MediaPlayer resources
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);


            // Little msg confirming end of sound
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), arrayResId[fragPosition][3], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

The issue is that the first two swiped screens (fragment Id 0 and 1) display the same image. I know that the first two fragments are created for performance purposes but the array only receives the values of the second screen (fragment)
....the following extract from the logs shows this :

```
I/SoundActivity: int position is : 0
I/SoundActivity: Value currentItem is : 0
I/SoundActivity: int position is : 1
I/SoundActivity: Value currentItem is : 0
I/Rootview: fragPosition is : 1
```

So how can I get the first fragment (Id:0) to display the first image of the array and not the second image (it seems as if it (ViewPager?) skips this data completely)....I really have run out of ideas...and what ever I seem to do mucks up the app.

Thanks for any suggestions !

Comment: Your question is wordy. You need to cut out extra information, such as what the app does. If you limit your description to what you want to show and what happens instead, could attract more answerers.

Comment: I agree, I will edit it. Thanks